# TypeScript use of global type inside namespace with same type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a type named the same as a global type. Specifically, an Event.

I've put my Event inside a namespace, which makes referring to it outside the namespace easy, but inside the namespace I can't refer to the global (or standard) one.

```
namespace Dot {
    export class Event {
        // a thing happens between two parties; nothing to do with JS Event
    }
    function doStuff(e : Event) {
       // Event is presumed to be a Dot.Event instead of usual JS event
       // Unable to refer to global type?
    }
}
function doStuff2(e : Event) {
    // Use of regular Event type, cool
}
function doStuff3(e : Dot.Event) {
    // Use of Dot event type, cool
}
```

I suspect this is simply not possible, but can this be confirmed? Any workarounds besides renaming the Dot.Event type?

Cheers

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/983

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* create a type to represent the global `Event` type, and use it within the namespace:

```
type GlobalEvent = Event;

namespace Dot {
    export class Event {
        // a thing happens between two parties; nothing to do with JS Event
    }
    function doStuff(e : GlobalEvent) {
       // Event is presumed to be a Dot.Event instead of usual JS event
       // Unable to refer to global type?
    }
}
function doStuff2(e : Event) {
    // Use of regular Event type, cool
}
function doStuff3(e : Dot.Event) {
    // Use of Dot event type, cool
}
```

But my recommendation would be to call your specialisation something else, for example `DotEvent`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. The majority of Dot's code uses DotEvent, it's just the event listeners inside Dot that need standard Event, so I'll be going with your GlobalEvent method. Cheers